# After Running simple maven project getting this error

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp

```
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:429)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what version of tomcat, java, eclipse, maven....  are you using and please read this guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before commenting :), Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem just recently.
The root cause was that jar library contained two identical class files of different signatures (sizes and creation dates). Class loader ran into error because it first tried to estimate bytecode length based on larger file, prepared buffer for that, and then loaded the smaller file, hence the output was left with trailing zeroes, which in turn led to this very exception.
This depends on the classloader, though. In my case code ran fine locally with java.lang classloader being used. But when deployed to Jboss, it used JBoss proprietary ModuleClassLoader and ran into the problem.

So if you are sure Java compilation versions match etc. then please check if the jar library in question contains two class files of identical names.

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassFormatException` indicates that you are attempting to use a class built for a newer version of Java than what you compiled your code to use. For example, you are compiling for Java 5 (Maven's default setting) but are trying to use a class built for Java 8.

See [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) for instruction on how to tell Maven what version you wish to use.

Comment: I am using java 8 and tomcat 8